# I have an error in Xcode while switching view controllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, breakpoints, programmatically-created

I wanted to be able to enter a view controller only if an entered password is correct.
i used the following code -

```
 if(([input isEqual:@"12"]))
{
    NSLog(@"change view controller");
    NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

but when i enter , Xcode gave me a sigbrt error, so i added an all exception breakpoint, but it goes to main.m and says 'thread 1:break point 1.1'.

thank you for reading and if you know the answer please answer

Comment: input is an integer variable.the code enters the if but does not switch storyboards properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
SecondViewController *second=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboardid"];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil];
```